# Increment a zero padded int in Bash loop

Tags: linux, bash, loops, unix, leading-zero

I'm trying to automate files rename/creation, I have a initial script for testing, I have already looked around I can't find anything related

here is my sample script

```
#!/bin/bash
file=`hostname`
if [[ -e $file.dx ]] ; then
    i="$(printf "%03d" 1)"
    while [[ -e $name-$i.dx ]] ; do
        let i++
    done
    name=$name-$i
fi
touch $name.dx
```

script work fine when the initial files is not present/exist but start goes wrong after the 3 occurrence as in the sh -x below

```
linux@cygwinhost ~/junkyard
$ sh -x exp.sh
++ hostname
+ name=cygwinhost
+ [[ -e cygwinhost.ext ]]
+ touch cygwinhost.ext

linux@cygwinhost ~/junkyard
$ sh -x exp.sh
++ hostname
+ name=cygwinhost
+ [[ -e cygwinhost.ext ]]
++ printf %03d 1
+ i=001
+ [[ -e cygwinhost-001.ext ]]
+ name=cygwinhost-001
+ touch cygwinhost-001.ext

linux@cygwinhost ~/junkyard
$ sh -x exp.sh
++ hostname
+ name=cygwinhost
+ [[ -e cygwinhost.ext ]]
++ printf %03d 1
+ i=001
+ [[ -e cygwinhost-001.ext ]]
+ let i++
+ [[ -e cygwinhost-2.ext ]]
+ name=cygwinhost-2
+ touch cygwinhost-2.ext

linux@cygwinhost ~/junkyard
$
```

after 001 it fallback to -2 without leading zeros,any input on what I did wrong is much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: it also appear to look for some environment variable $files, if it is not set, your script will create a hidden file named .dx in the current directory ... maybe move `touch` into the test block

Comment: Btw: without new process: `printf -v i "%03d" 1`

Comment: $file in the script seem a typo from me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that `001++` turns into `2` and not `002`. Why not use

```
i=1
printf -v padded_i "%03d" $i
while [[ -e ${name}-${padded_i}.dx ]] ; do
    let i++
    printf -v padded_i "%03d" $i
done
```

Less lines, but also more confusing:

```
i=1
while [[ -e ${name}-`printf "%03d" $i`.dx ]] ; do
    let i++
done
name=${name}-`printf "%03d" $i`.dx
```

*Update: Use the `printf -v padded_i` suggestion from the comments*

Comment: perfect solution for my problem! Thanks!

Comment: Lifting Cyrus's comment from the main post with bash you can use `printf -v i "%03d" $i` instead of using a sub-shell to do this.

Comment: @EtanReisner (or anyone) Does anyone have a ***reference*** citation for using `printf -v`. I know how it works, I just can't find anything that tells me that it works that way? Not `info coreutils/printf invocation`? Nowhere? I would just like to read it somewhere. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin we're talking about the builtin `printf`, so you need `help printf`, and certainly not `man` or `info`. Also, it's fully described in `man bash`, or the [reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Builtins).

Comment: Got it. Thank you. I was pulling my hair out on that one. openSuSE has a nice `man bashbuiltins` that contains only the bash builtins for convenience.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin RedHat/CentOS has a similar man page, conveniently (or not) llinked to most of the actual built-in names so `man shopt`/etc. pull it up for you automatically.